# How to create a dataframe with a for loop over years in csv

Tags: python, loops, csv, dataframe

I have csv files for each month and year from 2015 to 2019 and am trying to read them into a single dataframe and create a year variable that distinguishes each year so I can eventually merge them. The csv files are all named in the same way (for example: name_monthyear: "name_0119.csv" and "name_0218.csv").

I have done this successfully for each year on its own by creating a year folder 2019, 2018, etc. and doing each individually and then merging the dataframes, but I am wondering what might be more efficient code, particularly using a loop.

```
path19 ="C:\\...\\2019"

all_files19 = glob.glob(path19+"/*.csv")

li19 = []

for filename in all_files19:
    df19 = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col = None, header = 0)
    li19.append(df19)

final19 = pd.concat(li19, axis = 0, ignore_index = True)
final19['year'] = 2019
```

I expect the output to produce 5 dataframes: final15, final16, final17, etc., each with a year variable equal to year = 2015, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could do all 5 years simultaneously with os.walk():

```
import os

dataframes = []

path = "C:\\..."
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    year = os.path.basename(root)
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".csv"):
             filename = "{}/{}".format(root,file)
             df = pd.read_csv(filename,index_col=0,header=None)
             df["year"] = year
             dataframes.append(df)

final = pd.concat(dataframes, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```